# Windows 8 HOST Vagrant spinup GUEST Ubuntu dev followed with Ansible manage dev stack from GUEST

Tags: windows, vagrant, ansible

I am working with Vagrant to provision Ubuntu servers using bash. I would like to cut my teeth on Ansible however I understand that Ansible does not currently run on Windows Host.

Is something like the following a reasonable work-around?

On Windows Host, use Vagrant to spin-up a basic Ubuntu Dev Box, including Ansible tools. From the Guest Dev Box use Ansible to run local tasks to further build it out. From the Dev Box I would use Ansible to spin-up/manage other Digital Ocean droplets from this Dev Box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your easiest workaround is probably to [use virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) to start a linux/ubuntu virtual running on your Windows box, then to run Vagrant inside of that virtual. Yes, it's [turtles all the way down](https://superuser.com/a/312457/105576)- windows running virtualbox+ubuntu running virtualbox+ubuntu+vagrant.

Of course, the first layer won't be managed by Vagrant or Ansible, though you could do most of the configuration management after bootstrapping it.

Another option is to have a small dev box in your virtual hosting provider (Digital Ocean) where you manually install and launch vagrant/ansible from.

Alternately, dual boot or switch to a Linux or OSX machine :)

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. I was piddling around and found a way, within a VM guest to run Ansible tasks against the guest/localhost. So in theory, I could have the SMALLest possible Ubuntu Guest Dev Box manage itself and other guest or remote boxes/droplets. This guest Ansible would merely be responsible for running provision/config tasks. So on Windows, I could spin-up a basic local/remote boxes/droplets and manage them from the Ansible box. I have a pretty beefy Windows box. Just a matter of spec'ing out the smallest footprint box for running Ansible.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant by "you could do most of the configuration management after bootstrapping it". Ansible can manage local hosts- of course, it can't do so until some prereqs are installed.